# Email client app exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios

I am developing an app with xamarin studio. My goal is to connect to pop3 and download emails to my app.
I am using the following code but I am facing these issues:
 a) an exception on `sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop.gmail.com");`. (The authentication or decryption has failed).
b)everywhere  I have `sw.Flush()` I am taking exception: This operation is invalid until it is successfully authenticated.

```
TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
tcpclient.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995);            
System.Net.Security.SslStream sslstream = new SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream());
sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop.gmail.com"); 
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sslstream);
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslstream); 
sw.WriteLine("USER myusername");  
sw.Flush();
sw.WriteLine("PASS *****");
sw.Flush();
sw.WriteLine("RETR 1");
sw.Flush();
sw.WriteLine("Quit ");
sw.Flush();
string str = string.Empty;
string strTemp = string.Empty;
while((strTemp = reader.ReadLine()) !=null){
    if(".".Equals(strTemp)){
        break;
    }
    if(strTemp.IndexOf("-ERR") != -1){
        break;
    }
    str +=strTemp;
}
reader.Close();
sw.Close();
tcpclient.Close();
```

EDIT

I used mailkit and it is a great solution. I can retrieve emails but i have a problem. When i have download a number of mails(not specific number. For deferent account was deferent number of mails)
I am taking the following error:
`system.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on: `var message = client.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);`
My code for the login:

```
partial void btnlogin (NSObject sender)
{

        using (var client = new Pop3Client ()) {
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential (Convert.ToString(txtusername.Text).Trim(), Convert.ToString(txtpassword.Text).Trim());

            // Note: if the server requires SSL-on-connect, use the "pops" protocol instead
            var uri = new Uri (Convert.ToString("pops://pop.gmail.com"));

            using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource ()) {
                client.Connect (uri, cancel.Token);
                client.Authenticate (credentials, cancel.Token);

                int count = client.GetMessageCount (cancel.Token);
                var list= new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    var message = client.GetMessage (i, cancel.Token);
                    Console.WriteLine ("From: {0}", message.From);
                    list.Add(Convert.ToString(message.From));
                }

                client.Disconnect (true, cancel.Token);
            }
        }
                   }
```

Comment: You might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863381/send-imap-commands-to-gmail-using-c-sharp?rq=1 to see their code. Not 100% what you are after, but it might help. Noticed no one has replied yet so hopefully this will help you toward whatever the answer is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came here to suggest using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) instead of writing your own library for this. MailKit is also specifically meant to work with Xamarin (since I work at Xamarin). MailSystem.NET is pretty badly broken (I've ranted about it elsewhere on StackOverflow), so I would definitely not recommend using that.

That said, you may need to look at using this version of the [SslStream .ctor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145056%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as opposed to the one you are using. The problem *may* be that the default .ctor isn't validating the SSL certificate because it isn't "trusted".

Comment: Hello Thank you for your reply. I have the following issue: I run mailkit.mobile.sln with xamarin studio. Then when i try to build mailkit.IOS i am taking error that the MimeKit namespace could not be found.

Comment: You need to clone the other projects that are mentioned in the README.

Comment: ...Or you can use the NuGet packages. That might be easier?

Comment: hello, readme is an md file. when i run it, runs commands and all of them fail

Comment: Just open it in a text file or view https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit (GitHub renders the README.md as the main page)

Comment: Hello, mail kit works very good. Can you help me on how i can put ("Subject: {0}", message.Subject); on a list?

Comment: Is this what you are asking for? var list = new List<string> (); list.Add (message.Subject);

Comment: I have manage to put the email subject on a list but after i load 5 emails i am taking system.ArgumentOutOfRangeException on: var message = client.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);

Comment: I have edit my post with the login code. Thank you for helping me

Comment: Can you try creating a new MailKit.ProtocolLogger to pass to the Pop3Client .ctor so that you can get a log of the pop3 transactions? I'm wondering if maybe MailKit can't handle your server's STAT response.

Comment: The ArgumentOutOfRangeException should only ever get thrown if you are trying to download a message # that is higher than the count, but I don't see how that could happen with your loop.

Comment: Hello, My issue is that even i create a new gmail account that has only two messages i am taking the system.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. This happen on gmail

Comment: I asked for the log because I'm going to need that to track down the bug. Presumably something is different about your POP3 transaction or messages that you are downloading than the ones I'm using in my tests because I can't reproduce. That said, I just fixed a bug in MimeKit that would thrown an ArgumentOutOfRangeException when an unknown/unsupported charset was encountered, so maybe that was the problem?

Comment: How can i capture: return-path, received-from(the ip of the server), and enveloped from?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking

Comment: I want to capture the complete headers of an email

Comment: var value = message.Headers["Received"].Value;

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate a lot. Keep up your good work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an existing C# library to do this.

At one point in the past, I used [MailSystem.NET](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/) and was able to port their library to MonoTouch. I am not sure of its license works for you, but you will have a much better time using it than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that writing your own library for this would be a waste of anyone's time. I haven't tried Mail Kit yet (will definitely have to), but I have recently used [Rebex Mail](https://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/features/easy-to-use-api.aspx#pop3-download-mails) when I needed to backup my emails from my email server via POP3. Fortunatelly, it was a one time task only, so I did not have to pay as I only used their [30-day free trial](https://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/download.aspx) that did not have any limitation.

```
        using Rebex.Mail;
        using Rebex.Net;

        Pop3 client = new Pop3();
        client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", SslMode.Implicit);
        client.Login("gmailuser", "password");

        var messageInfos = client.GetMessageList(Pop3ListFields.FullHeaders);
        foreach (Pop3MessageInfo message in messageInfos)
            client.GetMessage(message.SequenceNumber, string.Format(@"C:\gmail-pop3-backup\{0}-{1}.eml", message.Subject, message.UniqueId));

        client.Disconnect();
```